# Link to files from different project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to target multiple platforms/frameworks with a library. Because of this, I created multiple projects in my solution (.Net3.5, .Net4.0, .Net4.5, Silverlight) **in the same folder**  which should all link to the same set of files.

Now, adding files to a project as links is fairly easy, however whenever I add a new file in my main project, I have to go through every 'targeting project' to link it again.

Is there a way to link to the files of a project instead of just the files itself?

So instead of this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\MyProject\SomeClass.cs">
        <Link>SomeClass.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile IncludeFrom="..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj">
        <Link>*</Link>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: If the libraries are nearly identical, you can also create the csproj files in the same folder. One per target. Then, include or not each file in the projects. If there is a implementation difference between your targets, you can use #if compiler directive to conditionally include part of the code.

Comment: @SteveB I have the csproj files in the same folder, one per target. The problem is the including, which has to be done manually for every new file that get's added.

Comment: you stated that you added each file as a target (leading to conclusion that you have your csproj in separate folders). what I said, is to simply "include" the file from visual studio. And this can be done for several file at once.

Comment: @SteveB Nope, same folder. I am also aware that one can include multiple files at once. This still doesn't solve the problem that if I create 1 new .cs file in my 'main' project, I have to 'refresh' every 'target project' in order to include that new file too.